# UPDATE number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, sql, update

Estoy haciendo una consulta UPDATE y me da el error :

> number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Entiendo que este error se debe a que los `bindParam()` y los `SET` del SQL no coinciden

```
     $sql2 = "UPDATE mat SET 
        pl=:id,usuario=:usuario,gps=:gps,br=:br,ma=:ma,bo=:bo,
        man=:man,dcs=:dcs,vvc=:vvc,cda=:cda,cra=:cra,pi=:pio,
        lin=:lin,arn=:arn,hid=:hid,com=:com,rpr=:rpr,
        neoc=:neoc,neol=:neol,bat=:bat,rprefle=:rprefle,estr=:estr,
        ben=:ben,sil=:sil,boc=:boc,cdag=:cdag,sco=:sco,
        mvl=:mvl,rad=:rad,cont=:cont,cu=:cu,cha=:cha,
        flo=:flo,comb=:comb,herr=:herr,tie=:tie,sac=:sac,
        mech=:mech,cdasdob=:cdasdob,bast=:bast,horn=:horn,
        carb=:carb,esq=:esq,rec=:rec,gven=:gven,raq=:raq,
        arva=:arva,abs=:abs,rpter=:rpter,rpimp=:rpimp,bya=:bya 
        WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pl = :id";
            if( $stmt2 = $bdd->prepare($sql2) ) 
            {
                                
                                $stmt2->bindParam('pl',$id); // 1
                                $stmt2->bindParam('usuario',$usuario);//2
            
                                $stmt2->bindParam('hid',$hid); //3
                                $stmt2->bindParam('com',$com); //4
                                $stmt2->bindParam('rpr',$rpr); //5
                                $stmt2->bindParam('neoc',$neoc); //6
                                $stmt2->bindParam('neol',$neol); //7
                                $stmt2->bindParam('lin',$lin); //8
                                $stmt2->bindParam('bat',$bat); //9
                                $stmt2->bindParam('bot',$bot);//10
                                $stmt2->bindParam('rprefle',$rprefle); //11
                                $stmt2->bindParam('estr',$estr); //12
            
                                $stmt2->bindParam('ben',$ben); //13
                                $stmt2->bindParam('sil',$sil); //14
                                $stmt2->bindParam('boc',$boc); //15
                                $stmt2->bindParam('cdag',$cdag);//16
                                $stmt2->bindParam('sco',$sco); //17
                                $stmt2->bindParam('mvl',$mvl); //18
                                $stmt2->bindParam('dcs',$dcs); //19
                                $stmt2->bindParam('rad',$rad); //20
                                $stmt2->bindParam('gps',$gps); //21
                                $stmt2->bindParam('br',$br);//22
            
                                $stmt2->bindParam('ma',$ma); //23
                                $stmt2->bindParam('man',$man); //24
                                $stmt2->bindParam('vvc',$vvc); //25
                                $stmt2->bindParam('arn',$arn); //26
                                $stmt2->bindParam('cda',$cda ); //27
                                $stmt2->bindParam('cont',$cont);//28
                                $stmt2->bindParam('cu',$cu); //29
                                $stmt2->bindParam('cha',$cha); //30
                                $stmt2->bindParam('flo',$flo); //31
                                $stmt2->bindParam('comb',$comb);//32
            
                                $stmt2->bindParam('herr',$herr);//33
                                $stmt2->bindParam('cra',$cra); //34
                                $stmt2->bindParam('tie',$tie); //35
                                $stmt2->bindParam('sco',$sco); //36
                                $stmt2->bindParam('mech',$mech); //37
                                $stmt2->bindParam('cdasdob',$cdasdob);//38
                                $stmt2->bindParam('bast',$bast);//39
                                $stmt2->bindParam('pio',$pio); //40
                                $stmt2->bindParam('horn',$horn);//41
                                $stmt2->bindParam('carb',$carb); //42
            
                                $stmt2->bindParam('esq',$esq);//43
                                $stmt2->bindParam('rec',$rec);//44
                                $stmt2->bindParam('gven',$gven);//45
                                $stmt2->bindParam('raq',$raq); //46
                                $stmt2->bindParam('arva',$arva);//47
                                $stmt2->bindParam('abs',$abs);//48
                                $stmt2->bindParam('rpter',$rpter); //49
                                $stmt2->bindParam('rpimp',$rpimp );//50
                                $stmt2->bindParam('bya',$bya );//51

...
}
```

La BBDD si doy en el apartado estrcuutra de la tabla, tiene 51 campos, por eso puse los comentarios del numero despues del bindParam()

Comment: Es correcto, ese error es porque no coinciden y es que empezamos mal desde el primer valor... lo que debes poner en `bindParam` es el marcador que está a la derecha, no el nombre de la columna, ¿me explico? Es decir, en vez de esto: `$stmt2->bindParam('pl',$id);`, debes poner esto: `$stmt2->bindParam(':id',$id);`  ... y así sucesivamente.

Comment: creo que si ... el primer bindParam no es `$stmt2->bindParam('pl',$id); // 1` si no `$stmt2->bindParam('ìd',$id); // 1`

Comment: Pues eso, corrige y verifica que todos los demás coincidan. Por cierto, ¿esa columna no es auto incremental no? Lo digo porque me extraña que se actualice un id.

Comment: Estaba mal solo el primero, gracias. No es autoincremental. Realmente no se actualiza, se obreescribe el mismo. Es que no sabia si en el update se podria dejar un campo de la tabla sin sobreescribir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo dos problemas en tu sentencia preparada:

1. Al menos en el primer `bindParam` estás usando el nombre de la columna para vincular, cuando se debe usar siempre el nombre del marcador. Cambia esto: `$stmt2->bindParam('pl',$id);` por esto: `$stmt2->bindParam(':id',$id);`
2. Estás usando marcadores repetidos en la consulta preparada. [El Manual de PHP es claro en ese aspecto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) (las negritas son mías):

   > Se debe incluir un único marcador de parámetro para cada valor que se
   > desee pasar a la sentencia cuando se llame a
   > `PDOStatement::execute()`. **No se puede usar un marcador de parámetro
   > con nombre con el mismo nombre más de una vez en una sentencia
   > preparada, a menos que el modo de emulación esté activado**.

No me vengas con: "pero dice *a menos que el modo de emulación esté activado*". Es cierto, pero activar el modo de emulación es peligroso, como se demuestra en [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967) sobre la Inyección SQL de este mismo sitio. Por tanto, simplemente, **no repitas marcadores**, es tan simple como poner un marcador distinto en la consulta y usarlo adecuadamente en la vinculación. Por ejemplo, para tus marcadores repetidos:

```
 $sql2 = "UPDATE mat SET 
   pl=:id,usuario=:usuario,gps=:gps, 

   ... resto de columnas en tu consulta ...

    WHERE usuario = :w_usuario AND pl = :w_id";
```

Y luego vinculas cada marcador:

```
$stmt2->bindParam(':id',$id); // 1
$stmt2->bindParam(':usuario',$usuario);

# ... resto de parámetros

# Estos son los del WHERE
$stmt2->bindParam(':w_id',$id); // 1
$stmt2->bindParam(':w_usuario',$usuario);
```

PD: Si sigue fallando, verifica que todos los demás parámetros coinciden en cantidad y en nombre.

Si quieres verificar la ejecución:

```
if ( $stmt2->execute() ) {
    printf( "Filas actualizadas: %d",$stmt2->rowCount() );
} else {
    printf( "Error ejecutando: %s",$stmt2->errorInfo[0][2] );
}
```

Comment: Perdona que te moleste de nuevo ... podrías actualizar este código ahceidno el execute () y recogiendo los errores de execute () ? Es que el log del servidor ya no me da error, pero no me esta actualizando la BBDD, por tanto el execute no lo esta haciendo y no sé por qué

Comment: @wiki Lo he agregado al final. NÓTESE que aquí se capturaría el mensaje de error de `$stmt2` directamente, dado que la clase PDO dispone de [un método `errorInfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) también para los objetos `PDOStatement` y se usa `rowCount()` para saber la cantidad de filas afectadas, al tratarse de una consulta `UPDATE`

Comment: muchas gracias ... hay alguna forma de poner con código que muestre consulta SQL con los valores del bindParam()?

Comment: No entendí tu último comentario @wiki

Comment: es que si que esta haciendo el execute() pero no está actualziando nada. Entonces me gustaria saber que consulta está ejecutando exacatamente. Si yo muestro la variable $sql2 no sé que valores está tomando la consulta de las variables $id, $usuario,... Lo que quiero ver es exacatmente la consulta que se ejcuta en la BBDD para saber porque me devuelve 0 filas afectadas

Comment: La consulta que está ejecutando es la última que hayas preparado y cuya referencia guardaste en `$stmt2`. Y precisamente el usar el `errorInfo()` del statement de captura el error del mismo y no de la conexión, para que la información sea precisa y no haya lugar a dudas. Ten en cuenta que un UPDATE en el que los datos serían los mismos que ya tenía esa tabla sería exitoso, pero afectaría cero filas ¿no será eso lo que ocurre en tu caso?

Comment: Entiendo, muchisimas gracias por las explicaciones. Lo que estaba pasando es que no estaba recibiendo bien el JSON, por tanto $id and $usuario eran null, y la setencia SQL se ejecutaba porque la clausula WHERE era correcta, pero obviamente afectada a 0 filas

Comment: @wiki otro nivel de comprobación que yo suelo usar es verificar aquello que yo llamo *datos esenciales*, es decir, aquellos que deberían ser requeridos para que todo funcione con normalidad. Así, si el id y el usuario son *datos esenciales*, yo añadiría otro filtro: `if ($id && $usuario) { //empezar con el bloque de la consulta } else { echo "Debes suministrar un ID y usuario"; }`

Comment: muchisimas gracias por compartir estas cosas conmigo y la comunidad, la verdad es que estoy aprendiendo mucho sobre buenas practicas y por tanto me cuesta menos depurar errores